# Express with socket.io emit - findOneAndUpdate

Tags: express, socket.io

quite new to socket io with express, i am using yo angular-express fullstack.

Save and delete all works fine, but when it come to **findOneAndUpdate** it doesn't seems to be work anymore. anyone can help? is there a way i can emit within the controller?

```
/**
 * Broadcast updates to client when the model changes
 */

'use strict';

var project = require('./project.model');

exports.register = function(socket) {
  project.schema.post('save', function (doc) {
    onSave(socket, doc);
  });
  project.schema.post('remove', function (doc) {
    onRemove(socket, doc);
  });
}

function onSave(socket, doc, cb) {
  socket.emit('project:save', doc);
}

function onRemove(socket, doc, cb) {
  socket.emit('project:remove', doc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Mongoose Document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes) The pre and post Middleware only hooks to     init, validate, save, remove. If you look the source code of findByIdAndUpdate function, you will find it do all its work in the query, which means it will by pass all pre and post's save middleware. (it has its own query middleware)

However, you can still make it work by rewrite the findByIDAndUpdate function into

```
Schema.findById(id, function(err, doc){
   // do some update on doc.
   doc.save(function(err){
       // all the additional works. 
   })
})
```

The save function will trigger the save middleware and it functions same as findByIDAndUpdate.